# Dynamic GETPIVOTDATA formula to SUM with different date ranges per column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have below an example pivot table with Countries as my columns, and Dates as my rows. The data for this pivot is based on A1:C13. Cells F1:G3 is what the user of this model can adjust. They can change the country and/or the date ranges.

What I am needing is a **single formula to output the total of their selection**. As my actual data set contains many countries, simply writing an nested IF statement won't suffice. The dataset also needs to be in pivot table - hence the GETPIVOTDATA requirement.

I've gotten about half of the way there using this formula here:

```
=SUM(GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of Value",$A$15,"Date",ROW(INDIRECT(F2&":"&F3)),"Country",F1:G1))
```

The problem here is that this formula is not dynamic for the differing date selections per country.

Can anyone assist?

[image]

Comment: Hi Chris, may I please know why you cannot do the calculations from the raw data table (A1:C13) but choose to do the calculations on the pivot table? For example, two simple SUMIFS formulas can easily work out the total you are seeking by doing the calculations on your raw data table. Also, have you considered using a power query to generate the desired output? The shortfall of the power query is that the user needs to manually refresh the data each time the parameters are changed (unless you use VBA to do an automatic refresh but marco workbook cannot be easily shared within an entity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a separate `GETPIVOTDATA` for each country:

```
=SUM(GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of Value",$A$15,"Date",ROW(INDIRECT(F2&":"&F3)),"Country",F1),GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of Value",$A$15,"Date",ROW(INDIRECT(G2&":"&G3)),"Country",G1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is there anyway to do this without separating this out? I have like 20 something countries in my actual data. Trying not to write a 'monster' formula :)

Comment: This gets me a little closer, but is ideally i would have all the date components combined opposed to separate row/indirects for each input. `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of Value",$A$15,"Date", CHOOSE({1,2},ROW(INDIRECT(F2&":"&F3)),ROW(INDIRECT(G28&":"&G3))),"Country",F1:G1),0))`

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @basic is the closest one for the original question, i.e. using GETPIVOTDATA to work out the total per given parameters.

If the calculation can be done on the original data table (Range A1:C13), then here is another solution to calculate the total.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A13=F1:G1)*(B2:B13>=F2:G2)*(B2:B13<=F3:G3)*(C2:C13))
```

In order to make the above calculation "dynamic", i.e. the calculation updates as the rows expands in the table, you can put the source data into a **Structured Reference Table**, give a **Name** to each column, such as "List_Ctry" for Column A, "List_Date" for Column B, and "List_Value" for Column C, then the range behind each name will update automatically when the source data changes. Using these names, the formula will be something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((List_Ctry=F1:G1)*(List_Date>=F2:G2)*(List_Date<=F3:G3)*List_Value)
```

You can also give names to the three parameters, being the range of country, range of start date, and range of end date. I will not illustrate further as if you understand the above concepts, you should be able to do this step yourself.

By using **Name** in the excel workbook, it will enable you to refer to the source data conveniently without the need to lay it out in your final report, so I do not understand what is the limitation here to stop you from calculating from the source data but have to work on the pivot table, as the calculations on pivot table are limited and not that intuitive.

[image]

Feel free to let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Thanks @Terry W. You raise a very good point. Sometime hard to see the forest through the trees... I guess I got stuck on the GETPIVOT() function and wanted to know what was possible with it. Will readjust my approach and as you suggest, go back to my original data source using SUMPRODUCT().

Comment: @Chris glad to help :) Excel in my eye is an open world or a sandbox. Full of fun :)